# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una celda con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero obtener el valor de la columna id de un único registro de una tabla con Jquery. Para lograrlo realizo un click uno de los botones y utilizo el siguiente script:

**Script**

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".td-id").val();
```

El this representa este valor:

```
$("#btn-eliminar")
```

Pero al momento de realizar no me trae el valor que yo quiero. ¿En qué me estaré equivocando?

**Tabla**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
                text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCloseButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
            })/*.then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                                    data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings().find(".td-id").val() },
                                    success: function () {

                                        Swal.fire(
                                            'Eliminado!',
                                            'Se eliminó una charla.',
                                            'success'
                                        )

                                    },
                                    error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                    }
                               });
                }
            })*/        
        });
    });
```

```css
.container{max-width:1700px}tr{display:flex;flex-direction:row}td,th{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-grow:1}.th-id{width:5%}.th-descripcion{width:21%}.th-sede{width:11%}.th-fecha,.th-hora{width:7%}.th-acciones,.th-lugar,.th-titulo{width:10%}.th-requisito{width:15%}.td-id{width:5%}.td-descripcion{width:21%}.td-sede{width:11%}.td-fecha,.td-hora{width:7%}.td-acciones,.td-lugar,.td-titulo{width:10%}.td-requisito{width:15%}.td-acciones{justify-content:space-evenly}
```

```html
<!--BOOTSTRAP-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--FONTAWESOME-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb0967b059.js"></script>

    <!--JQUERY VAL-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!--SWEET ALERT-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th class="th-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            ID_Charla
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Título de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Descripción de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Fecha de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hora de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Dirección de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Sede de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Requisitos para la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-acciones"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Acciones:
        </font></font></th>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                34
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de animación 3D
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                En esta charla veremos las novedades que nos traen Adobe y porque seran una buena opcion tenerlo en nuetra maquina. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se otorgara certificado a nombre de la nación por asistir.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                01:58
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/34?titulo=Taller%20de%20Animacion%203D&amp;descripcion=En%20esta%20charla%20veremos%20las%20novedades%20que%20nos%20trae%20Adobe%20y%20porque%20se%20seria%20una%20buena%20opcion%20tenerlo%20en%20nuetra%20maquina.%20Se%20otorgara%20certificado%20a%20nombre%20de%20la%20naci%C3%B3n%20por%20asistir.&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=01%3A58&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/34" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/34" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                38
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de Aviación Digital
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Lorem Ipsum es simplemente un texto de relleno de la industria de impresión y tipografía. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto ficticio estándar de la industria desde la década de 1500, cuando una impresora desconocida tomó una galera de tipos y la mezcló para hacer un libro de muestras tipo. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ha sobrevivido no solo cinco siglos, sino también el salto a la tipografía electrónica, permaneciendo esencialmente sin cambios. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se popularizó en la década de 1960 con el lanzamiento de las hojas de Letraset que contenían pasajes de Lorem Ipsum y, más recientemente, con un software de edición de escritorio como Aldus.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-17
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                02:21
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/38?titulo=Taller%20de%20Aviacion%20Digital&amp;descripcion=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20has%20been%20the%20industry%27s%20standard%20dummy%20text%20ever%20since%20the%201500s%2C%20when%20an%20unknown%20printer%20took%20a%20galley%20of%20type%20and%20scrambled%20it%20to%20make%20a%20type%20specimen%20book.%20It%20has%20survived%20not%20only%20five%20centuries%2C%20but%20also%20the%20leap%20into%20electronic%20typesetting%2C%20remaining%20essentially%20unchanged.%20It%20was%20popularised%20in%20the%201960s%20with%20the%20release%20of%20Letraset%20sheets%20containing%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passages%2C%20and%20more%20recently%20with%20desktop%20publishing%20software%20like%20Aldus&amp;fecha=2019-07-17&amp;hora=02%3A21&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/38" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/38" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                40
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                VALLE DE SILICONA DE TALLER DE MANUALIDADES
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Lorem Ipsum es simplemente un texto de relleno de la industria de impresión y tipografía. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto ficticio estándar de la industria desde la década de 1500, cuando una impresora desconocida tomó una galera de tipos y la mezcló para hacer un libro de muestras tipo. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ha sobrevivido no solo cinco siglos, sino también el salto a la tipografía electrónica, permaneciendo esencialmente sin cambios. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se popularizó en la década de 1960 con el lanzamiento de las hojas de Letraset que contenían pasajes de Lorem Ipsum y, más recientemente, con un software de edición de escritorio como Aldus.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                21:21
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/40?titulo=TALLER%20DE%20MANUALIDADES%20SILICON%20VALLEY&amp;descripcion=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20has%20been%20the%20industry%27s%20standard%20dummy%20text%20ever%20since%20the%201500s%2C%20when%20an%20unknown%20printer%20took%20a%20galley%20of%20type%20and%20scrambled%20it%20to%20make%20a%20type%20specimen%20book.%20It%20has%20survived%20not%20only%20five%20centuries%2C%20but%20also%20the%20leap%20into%20electronic%20typesetting%2C%20remaining%20essentially%20unchanged.%20It%20was%20popularised%20in%20the%201960s%20with%20the%20release%20of%20Letraset%20sheets%20containing%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passages%2C%20and%20more%20recently%20with%20desktop%20publishing%20software%20like%20Aldus&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=21%3A21&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/40" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/40" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                47
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller Desastres Naturales I
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Contrariamente a la creencia popular, Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente un texto aleatorio. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Tiene sus raíces en una pieza de la literatura latina clásica del 45 a. C., que tiene más de 2000 años de antigüedad. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Richard McClintock, un profesor de latín en Hampden-Sydney College en Virginia, buscó una de las palabras latinas más oscuras, consectetur, de un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y repasando las citas de la palabra en la literatura clásica, descubrió la indudable fuente. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum proviene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum".
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-17
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                23:23
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Es un hecho establecido que el contenido legible de una página distrae a un lector cuando
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Aquí hay muchas variaciones de los pasajes de Lorem Ipsum disponibles, pero la mayoría ha sufrido Altera.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/47?titulo=Taller%20Desastres%20Naturales%20I&amp;descripcion=Contrary%20to%20popular%20belief%2C%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20not%20simply%20random%20text.%20It%20has%20roots%20in%20a%20piece%20of%20classical%20Latin%20literature%20from%2045%20BC%2C%20making%20it%20over%202000%20years%20old.%20Richard%20McClintock%2C%20a%20Latin%20professor%20at%20Hampden-Sydney%20College%20in%20Virginia%2C%20looked%20up%20one%20of%20the%20more%20obscure%20Latin%20words%2C%20consectetur%2C%20from%20a%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passage%2C%20and%20going%20through%20the%20cites%20of%20the%20word%20in%20classical%20literature%2C%20discovered%20the%20undoubtable%20source.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20comes%20from%20sections%201.10.32%20and%201.10.33%20of%20%22de%20Finibus%20Bonorum%20et%20Malorum%22.&amp;fecha=2019-07-17&amp;hora=23%3A23&amp;direccion=It%20is%20a%20long%20established%20fact%20that%20a%20reader%20will%20be%20distracted%20by%20the%20readable%20content%20of%20a%20page%20whe&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/47" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/47" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                48
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de Aviación Digital 9
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Lorem Ipsum es simplemente un texto de relleno de la industria de impresión y tipografía. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto ficticio estándar de la industria desde la década de 1500, cuando una impresora desconocida tomó una galera de tipos y la mezcló para hacer un libro de muestras tipo. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ha sobrevivido no solo cinco siglos, sino también el salto a la tipografía electrónica, permaneciendo esencialmente sin cambios. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se popularizó en la década de 1960 con el lanzamiento de las hojas de Letraset que contenían pasajes de Lorem Ipsum y, más recientemente, con un software de edición de escritorio como Aldus.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                02:21
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/48?titulo=Taller%20de%20Aviacion%20Digital%209&amp;descripcion=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20has%20been%20the%20industry%27s%20standard%20dummy%20text%20ever%20since%20the%201500s%2C%20when%20an%20unknown%20printer%20took%20a%20galley%20of%20type%20and%20scrambled%20it%20to%20make%20a%20type%20specimen%20book.%20It%20has%20survived%20not%20only%20five%20centuries%2C%20but%20also%20the%20leap%20into%20electronic%20typesetting%2C%20remaining%20essentially%20unchanged.%20It%20was%20popularised%20in%20the%201960s%20with%20the%20release%20of%20Letraset%20sheets%20containing%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passages%2C%20and%20more%20recently%20with%20desktop%20publishing%20software%20like%20Aldus&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=02%3A21&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/48" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/48" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                49
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de animación 3D3D3D
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                En esta charla veremos las novedades que nos traen Adobe y porque seran una buena opcion tenerlo en nuetra maquina. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se otorgara certificado a nombre de la nación por asistir.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                01:58
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/49?titulo=Taller%20de%20Animacion%203D3D3D&amp;descripcion=En%20esta%20charla%20veremos%20las%20novedades%20que%20nos%20trae%20Adobe%20y%20porque%20se%20seria%20una%20buena%20opcion%20tenerlo%20en%20nuetra%20maquina.%20Se%20otorgara%20certificado%20a%20nombre%20de%20la%20naci%C3%B3n%20por%20asistir.&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=01%3A58&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/49" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-eliminar" href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/49" class="btn btn-primary" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Estas usando el mismo id para todos los botones.  El id debe ser unico.  Utiliza clases en lugar de ids.

Comment: pero con el this deberia ser suficiente

Comment: ok, enves de id usare clases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu código tienes varios errores que enumeraré a continuación:

1. Todos los botones eliminar tienen el mismo `id`, el id debe de ser único en el documento por cual deberías de usar `class`.
2. La mejor forma para navegar entre "padres" es utilizar el método `closest()` para llegar hasta el padre principal de la fila que sería la etiqueta `tr` y luego usar el método `find()` para seleccionar un elemento hijo determinado.
3. Estás usando `.val()` para capturar el contenido de un elemento `html`, en vez de `.val()` debes de usar `.text()` ya que `.val()` se usa únicamente para obtener el valor de elementos de tipo formulario.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
                text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCloseButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find(".td-id").text().trim())
                        /*$.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                                    data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings().find(".td-id").val() },
                                    success: function () {

                                        Swal.fire(
                                            'Eliminado!',
                                            'Se eliminó una charla.',
                                            'success'
                                        )

                                    },
                                    error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                    }
                               });*/
                }
            })      
        });
    });
```

```css
.container{max-width:1700px}tr{display:flex;flex-direction:row}td,th{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-grow:1}.th-id{width:5%}.th-descripcion{width:21%}.th-sede{width:11%}.th-fecha,.th-hora{width:7%}.th-acciones,.th-lugar,.th-titulo{width:10%}.th-requisito{width:15%}.td-id{width:5%}.td-descripcion{width:21%}.td-sede{width:11%}.td-fecha,.td-hora{width:7%}.td-acciones,.td-lugar,.td-titulo{width:10%}.td-requisito{width:15%}.td-acciones{justify-content:space-evenly}
```

```html
<!--BOOTSTRAP-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--FONTAWESOME-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb0967b059.js"></script>

    <!--JQUERY VAL-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!--SWEET ALERT-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th class="th-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            ID_Charla
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Título de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Descripción de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Fecha de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hora de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Dirección de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Sede de la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Requisitos para la charla:
        </font></font></th>
        <th class="th-acciones"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Acciones:
        </font></font></th>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                34
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de animación 3D
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                En esta charla veremos las novedades que nos traen Adobe y porque seran una buena opcion tenerlo en nuetra maquina. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se otorgara certificado a nombre de la nación por asistir.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                01:58
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/34?titulo=Taller%20de%20Animacion%203D&amp;descripcion=En%20esta%20charla%20veremos%20las%20novedades%20que%20nos%20trae%20Adobe%20y%20porque%20se%20seria%20una%20buena%20opcion%20tenerlo%20en%20nuetra%20maquina.%20Se%20otorgara%20certificado%20a%20nombre%20de%20la%20naci%C3%B3n%20por%20asistir.&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=01%3A58&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/34" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/34" class="btn btn-primary btn-eliminar" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                38
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller de Aviación Digital
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Lorem Ipsum es simplemente un texto de relleno de la industria de impresión y tipografía. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto ficticio estándar de la industria desde la década de 1500, cuando una impresora desconocida tomó una galera de tipos y la mezcló para hacer un libro de muestras tipo. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ha sobrevivido no solo cinco siglos, sino también el salto a la tipografía electrónica, permaneciendo esencialmente sin cambios. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se popularizó en la década de 1960 con el lanzamiento de las hojas de Letraset que contenían pasajes de Lorem Ipsum y, más recientemente, con un software de edición de escritorio como Aldus.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-17
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                02:21
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/38?titulo=Taller%20de%20Aviacion%20Digital&amp;descripcion=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20has%20been%20the%20industry%27s%20standard%20dummy%20text%20ever%20since%20the%201500s%2C%20when%20an%20unknown%20printer%20took%20a%20galley%20of%20type%20and%20scrambled%20it%20to%20make%20a%20type%20specimen%20book.%20It%20has%20survived%20not%20only%20five%20centuries%2C%20but%20also%20the%20leap%20into%20electronic%20typesetting%2C%20remaining%20essentially%20unchanged.%20It%20was%20popularised%20in%20the%201960s%20with%20the%20release%20of%20Letraset%20sheets%20containing%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passages%2C%20and%20more%20recently%20with%20desktop%20publishing%20software%20like%20Aldus&amp;fecha=2019-07-17&amp;hora=02%3A21&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/38" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/38" class="btn btn-primary btn-eliminar" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                40
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                VALLE DE SILICONA DE TALLER DE MANUALIDADES
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Lorem Ipsum es simplemente un texto de relleno de la industria de impresión y tipografía. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto ficticio estándar de la industria desde la década de 1500, cuando una impresora desconocida tomó una galera de tipos y la mezcló para hacer un libro de muestras tipo. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Ha sobrevivido no solo cinco siglos, sino también el salto a la tipografía electrónica, permaneciendo esencialmente sin cambios. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Se popularizó en la década de 1960 con el lanzamiento de las hojas de Letraset que contenían pasajes de Lorem Ipsum y, más recientemente, con un software de edición de escritorio como Aldus.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-16
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                21:21
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Jr. Manuel Raygada Mz.K -Lt.17 - Urb. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Paseo de la República Chorrillos - Telf: 252-1035
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Papel, Tijera, Goma, Colores, Serpentina y Título a nombre de la nación
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/40?titulo=TALLER%20DE%20MANUALIDADES%20SILICON%20VALLEY&amp;descripcion=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20has%20been%20the%20industry%27s%20standard%20dummy%20text%20ever%20since%20the%201500s%2C%20when%20an%20unknown%20printer%20took%20a%20galley%20of%20type%20and%20scrambled%20it%20to%20make%20a%20type%20specimen%20book.%20It%20has%20survived%20not%20only%20five%20centuries%2C%20but%20also%20the%20leap%20into%20electronic%20typesetting%2C%20remaining%20essentially%20unchanged.%20It%20was%20popularised%20in%20the%201960s%20with%20the%20release%20of%20Letraset%20sheets%20containing%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passages%2C%20and%20more%20recently%20with%20desktop%20publishing%20software%20like%20Aldus&amp;fecha=2019-07-16&amp;hora=21%3A21&amp;direccion=Jr.%20Manuel%20Raygada%20Mz.K%20-Lt.17%20-%20Urb.%20Paseo%20de%20la%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20Chorrillos%20-%20Telf%3A%20252-1035&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/40" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/40" class="btn btn-primary btn-eliminar" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-id"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                47
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-titulo"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Taller Desastres Naturales I
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-descripcion"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Contrariamente a la creencia popular, Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente un texto aleatorio. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Tiene sus raíces en una pieza de la literatura latina clásica del 45 a. C., que tiene más de 2000 años de antigüedad. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Richard McClintock, un profesor de latín en Hampden-Sydney College en Virginia, buscó una de las palabras latinas más oscuras, consectetur, de un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y repasando las citas de la palabra en la literatura clásica, descubrió la indudable fuente. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Lorem Ipsum proviene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum".
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-fecha"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                2019-07-17
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-hora"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                23:23
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-lugar"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Es un hecho establecido que el contenido legible de una página distrae a un lector cuando
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-sede"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                LIMA - SAN BORJA
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-requisito"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Aquí hay muchas variaciones de los pasajes de Lorem Ipsum disponibles, pero la mayoría ha sufrido Altera.
            </font></font></td>
            <td class="td-acciones">
                <a href="/Charlas/MostrarInscritos/47?titulo=Taller%20Desastres%20Naturales%20I&amp;descripcion=Contrary%20to%20popular%20belief%2C%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20not%20simply%20random%20text.%20It%20has%20roots%20in%20a%20piece%20of%20classical%20Latin%20literature%20from%2045%20BC%2C%20making%20it%20over%202000%20years%20old.%20Richard%20McClintock%2C%20a%20Latin%20professor%20at%20Hampden-Sydney%20College%20in%20Virginia%2C%20looked%20up%20one%20of%20the%20more%20obscure%20Latin%20words%2C%20consectetur%2C%20from%20a%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20passage%2C%20and%20going%20through%20the%20cites%20of%20the%20word%20in%20classical%20literature%2C%20discovered%20the%20undoubtable%20source.%20Lorem%20Ipsum%20comes%20from%20sections%201.10.32%20and%201.10.33%20of%20%22de%20Finibus%20Bonorum%20et%20Malorum%22.&amp;fecha=2019-07-17&amp;hora=23%3A23&amp;direccion=It%20is%20a%20long%20established%20fact%20that%20a%20reader%20will%20be%20distracted%20by%20the%20readable%20content%20of%20a%20page%20whe&amp;sede=LIMA%20-%20SAN%20BORJA" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ver Inscritos">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EditarCharlas/47" class="btn btn-primary" title="Actualizar charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="/Charlas/EliminarCharla/47" class="btn btn-primary btn-eliminar" title="Eliminar Charla">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <a id="btn-prueba" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-vial" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que no estás considerando los hijos del `<td>`, los `<font>`

con `$(this).parent().siblings().find(".td-id")` obtienes el `<td class="td-id">` pero te faltan los hijos, en este caso son dos `<font>`:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".td-id").first() //aquí llegas al primer <font>
.children().first() //aquí al segundo <font>
.html() //aquí obtienes el valor que quieres
```